# I have a issue with my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

It may seem really really simple seeing its only a button and I'm using the `window.location.href = 'pagehere.html';` It may seem simple but lots of help will be appreciated. I am kinda new to this so give me some slack if it's something simple.

Here is the code, HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

```js
var logpopup = document.getElementById('Login_Popup');
/* creating variables and calling ID's from HTML document */
var logbutton = document.getElementById('Login_Button');
/**/
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('popup_x')[0];
/**/
var registerlink = document.getElementById('Register_Button');
/*
var username,x,y;
*/
/**/
logbutton.onclick = function() {
  "use strict"; /* should be run in strict mode */
  logpopup.style.display = 'block';
  /* if "logbutton" is clicked, display "logpopup" */
};
span.onclick = function() {
  "use strict";
  logpopup.style.display = 'none';
  /* if "span" is flicked, close/do not display "logpopup" */
};
window.onclick = function() {
  /* (window is a default variable) If event running is "logopopup" and window is clicked, close/do not display logopopup */
  "use strict";
  if (event.target === logpopup) {
    logpopup.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
/*
function outputname() {
    x=document.getElementById("popup_form");
    y=x.elements["username"].value;                 not working yet
    name = "John";
    document.write("Hello "+y+"<br>");
}
*/

registerlink.onclick = function() {
  /* when "registerlink" is clicked, call "Test3Register.html" */
  "use strict";
  window.location.href = 'CarCompanyRegister.html';
  return;
};

var registersubmitvalidate = document.getElementById('register_button_validation');

registersubmitvalidate.onclick = function() {
  "use strict";
  window.location.href = 'CarCompany.html';
  return;
};

var dropdownArray = ['dropdown_content1', 'dropdown_content2', 'dropdown_content3', 'dropdown_content4', 'dropdown_content5', 'dropdown_content6', 'dropdown_content7', 'dropdown_content8', 'dropdown_content9'];

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  "use strict";
  for (var i = 0; i < dropdownArray.length; i++) {
    var rightdropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownArray[i]);
    if (event.target != rightdropdown) {
      rightdropdown.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
window.onload = function() {
  "use strict";
  var dict = {
    'left_side_button1': 'dropdown_content1',
    'left_side_button2': 'dropdown_content2',
    'left_side_button3': 'dropdown_content3',
    'mid_side_button4': 'dropdown_content4',
    'mid_side_button5': 'dropdown_content5',
    'mid_side_button6': 'dropdown_content6',
    'right_side_button7': 'dropdown_content7',
    'right_side_button8': 'dropdown_content8',
    'right_side_button9': 'dropdown_content9'
  }
  document.onclick = function(e) {
    for (var l in dict) {
      if (e.target === document.getElementById(l)) {
        document.getElementById(dict[l]).style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
button,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
a {
  /* State that these particular elements be "fantasy" */
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

#main_body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #dedede;
}

#top_body {
  /* for the sake of having no margin */
}

#top_container {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 0px;
  /*background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, ellipse farthest-side, #8CFBFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%); */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#666, #000);
  position: relative;
  color: aliceblue;
}

#top_header {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header_hgroup li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header_text {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#Login_Button {
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  border: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

#Register_Button {
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  border: 0px;
}

#top_nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;
  text-align: left;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#top_nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav1 {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.class1 {
  display: none;
}

.mid_container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 105px;
}

#container_top_padder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#container_top_padder li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: none;
}

#individual_top_padder_text {
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#vehicle_1_header {
  /* not assigned at the moment */
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, ellipse farthest-side, #8CFBFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#vehicle_2_header {
  /* not assigned at the moment */
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, ellipse farthest-side, #8CFBFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#vehicle_3_header {
  /* not assigned at the moment */
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, ellipse farthest-side, #8CFBFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.compare_sections_titles {
  /* not assigned at the moment */
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#left_section {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

#left_side_button1 {
  /*background-color: aqua; */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#dropdown_content1 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content1 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown_content1 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#left_side_button2 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#dropdown_content2 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content2 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown_content2 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#left_side_button3 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
}

#dropdown_content3 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content3 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown_content3 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#mid_section {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

#mid_side_button4 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#dropdown_content4 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content4 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown_all_text {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

#dropdown_content4 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

#mid_side_button5 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#dropdown_content5 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content5 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown_content5 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

#mid_side_button6 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
}

#dropdown_content6 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content6 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown_content6 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

#right_section {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

#right_side_button7 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#dropdown_content7 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content7 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown_content7 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#right_side_button8 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#dropdown_content8 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#dropdown_content8 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown_content8 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#right_side_button9 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c6c6c6);
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
}

#dropdown_content9 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown_content9 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#compare_dialog_container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#compare_dialog_container li {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#Red_compare_button {
  color: white;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff3e3e, #ff0000);
  padding: 10px;
}

#dropdown_content9 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.popup_container {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.popup {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 28px;
  /* Stating that all corners should be rounded */
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  /*<*/
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.popup_x {
  color: grey;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup_x:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup_head {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, ellipse farthest-side, lightblue 0%, white 100%);
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}

.popup_bod {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.loginform_bod_text {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup_foot {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, ellipse farthest-side, lightblue 0%, white 100%);
  border-top: 1px solid #888;
}

.loginform_foot_text {
  color: black;
  font-weight: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: none;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.loginform_foot_text:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#mid_container_register {
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  align-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 105px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#register_section {
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.Register_subtitle {
  color: #999999;
}

.Single_span_text_coloring {
  color: #0000CC;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#register_article_footer {
  color: gray;
}

#left_side_nav {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888;
  margin-right: 75px;
  background-color: white;
}

#left_side_nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: disc;
  font-weight: none;
  color: black;
}

#left_side_nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: default;
}

#bottom_container {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body id="main_body">

  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CarCompanyCSS.css">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=deive-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CarCompanyJavascript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <div id="top_container">
    <header id="top_header">
      <hgroup id="header_hgroup">
        <a class="header_text">
          <li>
            <h1>Title</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <!-- Add specificity if needed -->
        <a class="header_text">
          <li>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
          </li>
        </a>
        <button id="Login_Button">Login</button>
        <div id="Login_Popup" class="popup_container">
          <!-- Popup creation -->
          <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup_head">
              <span class="popup_x">x</span>
              <h2>Login</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_bod">
              <form>
                <br />
                <label>Username:</label><br />
                <input class="loginform_bod_text" type="text" name="Username" maxlength="10" placeholder="Username" /><br />
                <label>Password:</label><br />
                <input class="loginform_bod_text" type="password" name="Password" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_foot">
              <br />
              <a class="loginform_foot_text" href="Forgot Password.html">Reset Password</a>
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </hgroup>
    </header>
    <nav id="top_nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="nav1">Cars</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="mid_container_register">
    <hr />
    <section id="left_side_nav">
      <article>
        <nav>
          <ol>
            <a href="CarCompany.html">
              <li>Home</li>
            </a>
            <hr />
            <a href="CarCompany.html">
              <li>My Account</li>
            </a>
            <hr />
            <a href="CarCompany.html">
              <li>Category</li>
            </a>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id="register_section">
      <header>
        <hgroup>
          <h3><u><b>Register</b></u></h3>
          <p>
            <h5 class="Register_subtitle">To submit, all fields must be completed.</h5>
          </p>
          <p>
            <h5 class="Register_subtitle"> Fields marked with a <span class="Single_span_text_coloring"> * </span> are required</h5>
          </p>
          <hr />
          <br />
        </hgroup>
      </header>
      <form>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <br /><input type="text" name="Username" maxlength="10"><span class="Single_span_text_coloring"> * </span><br /><br />

        <label>Password:</label>
        <br /> <input type="password" name="Password" maxlength="16"><span class="Single_span_text_coloring"> * </span><br /><br />

        <label>E-Mail:</label>
        <br /> <input type="text" name="E-Mail"><span class="Single_span_text_coloring"> * </span><br /><br />

        <label>Age:</label>
        <br /> <select type="option" name="Age">
    <option></option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    </select><br /><br />
        <p>Security Question:</p><br /><select type="select" name="Security Question">
    <option>Please select one.</option>
    <option>What was my school teachers first name?</option>
    <option>Whats my favourite chip flavour?</option>
    <option>What type was my first car?</option>
    <option>What was the name of my first school?</option>
    <option>What are my parents names?</option>
    <option>How many siblings do i have?</option>
    <option>What was the address of my first house?</option>
    </select><br /> <br />
        <p>Answer:</p> <br /> <input type="text" name="Answer">
        <button>Why</button><br /><br />

        <button id="register_button_validation">Submit</button>
        <!-- Not working... -->

      </form>
      <footer id="register_article_footer">
        <p>Check your mail to validate your account</p>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <br />
    <hr />
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="CarCompanyJavascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_, _"Introduce the problem before you post any code: In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."_

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: what is your Question?

Comment: Where's the jQuery?

Comment: at least put some effort to frame your question, instead of just putting all the code here and saying I have problem.

Comment: You need to run your code through a validator, you have a lot of errors with your html.  But your main problem will be that you are not preventing the default action of your form so instead of redirecting to your js page, you are just returning to the present page as the form is being sent (not sure why you need a form as you don't actually have an action or method and you seem to process everything with your js)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('Register_Button');
```

the only approaching id in your html is `register_button_validation` so `getElementById("some_non_existing_id")` returns `null`. And you cannot set the `onclick` method on `null`.

As an exception as been thrown, the remaining code can't be executed, and the `registersubmitvalidate.onclick` cannot be bound so this function can't get executed :

```
registersubmitvalidate.onclick = function() {
  "use strict";
  window.location.href = 'CarCompany.html';
  return;
};
```

Comment: There is no element in the html with the id `Register_Button` or `register_button` so not sure why this is being upvoted so much

Comment: `register_button_validation`, sorry

Comment: OP is setting that variable properly: 
`var registersubmitvalidate = document.getElementById('register_button_validation');`

Comment: check the edit... The fact is `Register_Button` does not exist.

Comment: Doesn't matter if that element exists or not, OP is having problem with the validation button click (which is bound correctly), not the non existent button click

Comment: That wasn't obvious when I answerred.

Comment: And actually, it does matter, if an error is thrown, the remaining code won't get executed... So, please, tell me what's wrong.

Comment: ok, I'll give you that one

Comment: so why downvote ?

Comment: Because your original answer was very wrong - I have removed it now